# How to signal from parent process to the child?

Tags: c, linux

How can i send signal from parent process to the child?
After i write to the pipe i want to send signal to the child process.

```
 pid_t pid;
     int filds[2];
     pipe(filds);
     char *args[150] = {"./draw.out", NULL};
     char buff = '\0';

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {  // fork a child process/
         printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
         exit(1);
     } else if (pid == 0) {
         execvp(args[0], args); // execute the command
     } else {  // for the parent
         char btnPressed = getch();

         while (btnPressed != 'q'){
             btnPressed = getch();
             write(filds[1],buff, BUFF_SIZE); 
             //signal
         }
         // signal finish game.
     }
```

Comment: Anyone besides me remotely curious (a) what `BUFF_SIZE` is, and (b) how this possibly compiles with warnings-as-errors passing `char` as the second argument of `write` ?

Comment: Signals are sent my means of `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig)` system call. PID of the child process is available to the parent as the result value of `fork()`.

Comment: You're going to run into an issue, as the child process ceases to exist with the `exec` call. However, if `draw.out` is trying to read from the pipe, that should be enough, as I believe that `read` is by default blocking.

Comment: `write(filds[1],buff, BUFF_SIZE);` This should not compile cleanly. If you didn't get any warning, throw away your compiler and get a working one. If you did get a warning, find out how to set up your compiler so that warnings are treated as errors. Keep that setting for ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kill(PID, SIGwhatever);
```

however this is probably a poor choice; the better solution is

```
close(filds[1]);
```

and handle close of input in the child. I think you're missing a

```
dup2(files[0],0);
```

in the child path as well.